# Set magit to pull with rebase by default

Tags: magit

Recent versions of Magit (>=2.3) have snazzy new popups with variables that feature more than two options.

[image]

Here, <kbd>r</kbd> cycles between the three values: `true`, `false`, and `default:false`.

I almost always pull with rebase, so how can I make the default `default:true` instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default for the repository can be changed from the branch popup: <kbd>b M-r...</kbd>. The branch popup is used for creating, checking out, *and modifying* branches.

To set the global default use `git config --global pull.rebase true`.

Comment: When I change the default for a repository, does it modify files in the `.git` folder?

Comment: Yes. (Same for `branch.<name>.rebase`.)